# getting all lines in variable until it comes across a specific word

Tags: php, html

the idea is that the code searches through the lines and when it finds a matching line it will store it in a variable and than write it to a file. is there a possibility that when it finds a match it keeps storing all lines in to the variable until it comes across a specific word in the textfile(and continue searching for a match after that)?
like:

```
matchingline1
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
SPECIFICWORD
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
matchingline2
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
SPECIFICWORD
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
```

Result:

```
matchingline1
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager    
matchingline2
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
```

code:

```
<?php
    $input = file("FILENAMEWITHDATA.TXT", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $filter = file("FILTERINGFILE.TXT", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
    $new_line = "\n";  // \r\n
    $result = "";

    function pass_filter($line, $filter) {
           $i = count($filter);
           $res = false;
           while (--$i > -1 ) {
              if (strrpos($line, $filter[$i]) > 0){                                         
                    $res = true;
                    continue;
              }
           }
      return $res;
   }



for ($j = 0; $j < count($input); $j++) {

      if ( pass_filter($input[$j], $filter) ) {
         $result .= $input[$j] . $new_line . $input[($j+1)] . $new_line;
      }
   $j++;
}

file_put_contents("RESULT.TXT",$result);

?>
```

Comment: the question is how can i do this?

Comment: In your input example you have "matchingline1" and "matchingline2". In the outpout it`s just "matchingline". Please explain.

Comment: my fault, editing it right now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can neasily be done using `preg_match_all()`, working sample code can be found at http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9529471a3c1fe4a304295afbe440ca1ab137d61

```
<?php
$input = 'matchingline1
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
SPECIFICWORD
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
matchingline2
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
SPECIFICWORD
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager';

preg_match_all('/^(matchingline.*)SPECIFICWORD/msU', $input, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(235) "matchingline1
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
"
  [1]=>
  string(400) "matchingline2
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
sdffadadfdfadafs randomlineoftext gdfwaweaddsfgreager
"
}
```

Explanation of regex:

- ^ = Start at beginning of line, followed by
- (matchingline.*) = match the string "matchingline" and all of the following chars, followed by
- SPECIFICWORD = match string "SPECIFICWORD"
- /msU = Modifiers

  - m = Treat string as multiple lines, makes `^` match the start of every line, default is to match only beginning of string
  - s = make `.` match any char, even line breaks
  - U = ungreedy, stop as soon as possible

So this regex matches all text starting at the beginning of a line which starts with "matchingline" up until it finds a string "SPECIFICWORD".

Using brackets like in `(matchingline.*)` makes this specific part accessible, in our example by using `$matches[1]`.

Comment: oke.... the specificword string does not only exist of specificword (there is a variable behind it.... thats a problem

Comment: To use `$filter` instead of "SPECIFICWORD" use `preg_match_all("/^(matchingline.*)$filter/msU", $input, $matches);`

Comment: i see... but what if the specificword always has the filter in it... the specific word is like the filter with an random other number behind it

Comment: Like your string starts with "a" and ends with "aa"? That won't be a problem.

Comment: Hope you get the idea: `preg_match_all("/^($start.*)$end/msU", $input, $matches);`. Use `$start` and `$end` to specify start and stop token.

Comment: HERO! THANK YOU SO MUCH :D

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this,

```
$searches = explode('SPECIFICWORD ', $all_text);
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: wont work because there is not always a specific word for each matching line.. or can you go around that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), then iterate over lines with while and [fgets](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php).

This will allow you to iterate trough file reading one line at a time.
While iterating you can check if line is empty, is equal searched value and script should collect next lines or maybe line contains specific word and stops collecting.

Don't forget to [fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php) file when after loop.

Example:

```
function pass_filter($file, $startLine, $stopWord)
{
    if (!$handle = fopen($file, 'r')) {
        throw new Exception('Can\'t open');
    }

    $collecting = false;
    $result = [];

    while($line = fgets($handle)) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if (strlen($line) === 0) {
            continue;
        }

        if ($line === $startLine) {
            $collecting = true;
        }

        if (strpos($line, $stopWord) !== false) {
            $collecting = false;
        }

        if ($collecting) {
            $result[] = $line;
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);

    return $result;
}
```